# How do I get better auras?

Tags: tennis-club-story

My tennis players only ever get the blue aura, I see my opponents all have purple auras.  How do I improve my auras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike the other kairosoft games, there are no aura tiers Tennis Club Story.  Blue aura occurs when your mental bar is tilted in your favor and the purple aura occurs when the opponent's mental bar crosses their threshold.